# Publish a new post on Octopress from another computer

Tags: blogs, octopress

I am currently exploring Octopress. One question popped up during the course of my work - is there an easy way to publish a post from a random computer/device. I mean - if I do this via rake new_post['title'] I must have the whole thing set up on the machine I am doing it from - Ruby, gems etc.. Is there an easier way - like create a markdown document and than just send it to the Github repository?

Comment: If you decide to clone everything, [here's a blog post](http://blog.zerosharp.com/clone-your-octopress-to-blog-from-two-places/) you may find helpful.

Comment: Yeah, that's how I do this at present from home and work, but I am searching for a way to post from, say, a public computer or the computer of a friend.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there is no way to do that.

Since octopress is based on [Jekyll](http://jekyllrb.com/), every page is rendered as follows:

1. Render Liquid
2. Convert if a converter exists for that extname(e.g. `.markdown`)
3. Render layout(s) recursively.

That is to say, for such a static website, it's unable to show a markdown document directly.

On the other hand, if what we send to repo is not a markdown file which must be converted to html to be showed, but a html directly, it's also not possible to make the site work normally.

Since not only the post page itself should be generated, but also many related parts such as index page, categories and so on.

In one word, octopress is static, we need generation before deployment.

Reference:[Allow markdown to not be compiled to html](https://github.com/mojombo/jekyll/issues/1216)